# Problem docker-compose with laravel nginx not working on production

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I wrote a docker-compose.yml with nginx, mysql, and an application laravel with a dockerfile.

My docker-compose :

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app_back:
    build:
  
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: dreamy_back   
    container_name: dreamy-back-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    networks:
      - dreamy
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: dreamy-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - app_back
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 4ztgeU%
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    networks:
      - dreamy
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17-alpine
    container_name: dreamy-back-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/vhosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - dreamy
networks:
  dreamy:
    driver: bridge
```

My dockerfile for an laravel application  :

I execute composer install inside the container.

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm
# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Set working directory

WORKDIR /var/www
```

My nginx conf :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app_back:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

On my laptop it's working but on my vps server I get an error 500.

My docker should be accessible port 8000

[My nginx logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60phT.png)

Comment: Error 500 could be anything. Just doublechecking: Did you run `composer install` in your container? I see you add composer to the image, but I don't see you using it. Also, do you have the .env file added to the container?

Comment: Check your nginx log for any errors.

Comment: I run these commands after docker-compose up :
docker-compose exec app_back composer install;
docker-compose exec app_back php artisan key:generate
docker-compose exec app_back php artisan migrate;

Comment: @Pierre So if you log into your container(s), you can see the .env and the vendor folder in your laravel folder?

Comment: @Techno yes that's right and everything works on my personal computer

Comment: @Pierre can you see `vendor` folder in your container after running `docker-compose exec app_back composer install` command? And please provide deployment `.env` file

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli , yes i see the vendor folder in my container

Comment: @Pierre is it laravel's default 500 error page that you are seeing or nginx returns 500 page

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli it's nginx return 500 page

Comment: Log nginx : dreamy-back-nginx | 85.169.101.162 - - [20/Dec/2022:12:48:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Comment: What about `error.log`?

Comment: I change this and no changements

Comment: @Pierre , comming back at your statement (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74860409/problem-docker-compose-with-laravel-nginx-not-working-on-production?noredirect=1#comment132116433_74860409) Can you verify the same on your production environment? I think this might be the issue

Comment: I checked and it is the same in production. No log in my error.log and access.log in my container

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE  - I found the problem, in production the application does not display laravel errors. So it is the default ngynx page that is displayed. The error was the right for the storage file.

Thank you for your help.